# Python deleting rows with a specific value in existing csv file

Tags: python

In Python I am using an existing csv file for a project. One of it's columns is sex. So, the values are either m,f,sex, or ' '.(blank)

I only want the rows with m and f, so how do I delete the rows that have the word sex or with no value in it?

Comment: What do you want to do ? What is your aim here ?

Comment: I only want to use the rows that have the value m or f. So I need to delete the other rows that don't how those two values using python

Comment: A couple rows have the value 'sex' instead of 'm' or 'f' and a couple rows are blank. So how do I delete those excel rows in python. I know this can be done easily in excel, but I need to do it using python

Comment: Seems I was posting an answer in the same time as someone else :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may read the csv file into a pandas dataFrame, then select the rows which are not blank.

```
import pandas as pd

inFile = "path/to/your/csv/file"
sep = ','
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=inFile, low_memory=False, encoding='utf-8', sep=sep)

df_mf = df.loc[(df['Sex']=='m') | (df['Sex']=='f')]
```

Answer (score 1):

well here's a help in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('your file path')
filt = (df['sex'] =='m') | (df['sex'] == 'f')

updated_df = df.loc[filt,['other','columns','list']]
updated_df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv', index = False)
```